# execvp() never finishes on pipe

Tags: c, printf, pipe, echo, execvp

I am taking an OS course and writing a shell. And I encountered a problem about execvp() and pipe. The following code is a simplified version of the code where problem happens.

```
static pid_t
command_exec(command_t *cmd, int *pass_pipefd) //the function that executes commands. this function will be called multiple times if the input line contains multiple commands. Ex. "echo abc | cat"
{
    pid_t pid = 0; //child pid
    int pipefd[2]; //array for pipe
    if(cmd->controlop == CMD_PIPE){
        //if the control operation of the command is pipe(to the left of a '|'), create a pipe
        pipe(pipefd);
    }
    pid = fork();
if(pid==0){ //child branch
    dup2(*pass_pipefd,0);//redirect stdin to the pipe from last command
    if(strcmp(cmd->argv[0],"cd")){ //if the command is not cd
        if(cmd->controlop == CMD_PIPE){
            dup2(pipefd[1],1); 
            //if command's control operation is pipe(to the left of a '|'), redirect stdout to pipefd[1]
        }
        if(execvp(cmd->argv[0],cmd->argv)<0)//execute the command,use stdin as input and stdout as output(but they may be redirected)
            printf("%s fails\n",arg[0]);
    }
    exit(0);
}else{//if parent
    wait(NULL); //wait for the child
    if(cmd->controlop == CMD_PIPE){
        *pass_pipefd = pipefd[0];//if command's control operation is pipe(to the left of a '|'), set *pass_pipefd to the output of the pipe array.
        return pid;
    }
}
```

If the input is "echo a", then the output is no problem. execvp() will finish and wait(NULL) in the parent will not wait forever. However if the input is "echo abc | cat", then "abc" will be output to the terminal but the program will be stuck. the cause is that the execvp() that executes "cat" never finishes so the wait(NULL) in parent waits forever.I know that execvp() doesn't return but it should eventually finish. I think I may mess up the stdin and stdout redirection things but I can't find the bug.

Comment: Put simply, you aren't closing enough file decriptors.  In particular, the parent must close both ends of the pipe.  You also don't have the parent wait synchronously (though that isn't part of your problem here).  You must let the processes in the pipeline all run at once, because if you have `A | B` and you wait for `A` to finish before launching `B` but `A` produces more data than fits in a pipe buffer (4 KiB to about 64 KiB, IIRC, depending on platform), then `A` never exits, so `B` never starts, so the system deadlocks.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ Since your code is not executable — it is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — I'm not inclined to try fixing it; I can't tell sufficiently how it is called and what the input data looks like.  But `cat` doesn't terminate until its standard input returns EOF, and while there's a process with the write end of the pipe open, its standard input won't return EOF.  But your shell code fairly clearly still has the pipe open, so you have deadlock again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, you aren't closing enough file decriptors. In particular, the parent must close both ends of the pipe.

Also, in a shell, you can't have the parent wait synchronously for each child to finish before running the next (though that isn't part of your problem here). You must let the processes in the pipeline all run at once, because if you have `A | B` and you wait for `A` to finish before launching `B` but `A` produces more data than fits in a pipe buffer (4 KiB to about 64 KiB, IIRC, depending on platform), then `A` never exits, so `B` never starts, so the system deadlocks.

Since your code is not executable — it is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — I'm not inclined to try fixing it; I can't tell sufficiently how it is called and what the input data looks like. But `cat` doesn't terminate until its standard input returns EOF, and while there's a process with the write end of the pipe open, its standard input won't return EOF. But your shell code fairly clearly still has the pipe open, so you have deadlock again.